# Hibernate version to support Oracle12cDialect and JPA 2.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, websphere, websphere-8

I deploy my application (Spring + Hibernate + JPA) to Websphere application server and application connects to Database version Oracle 12c.

In order to support Oracle 12c DB I need Oracle12c Dialect and Websphere Application server(8.5.5) supports JPA 2.0.

I see Hibernate versions > 5 are only providing Oracle12cDialect and don't provide JPA 2.0 instead it has (`hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar`)

JPA 2.0 is supported by V3.5 to V4.2 (But These versions are not available with Oracle12cDialect)

When I use `hibernate-entitymanager.5.0.7.Final.jar` I get the below error during the service call.

**Error :**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl incompatible with javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
                at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:110) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:57) ~[hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:130) ~[hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:46) ~[hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
                at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1221) ~[hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final
```

If I try keeping `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar` scope as provided from application, it creates the below issue as the `AttributeConverter` class is not available in Websphere JPA 2.0

```
ERROR o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name &#39;entityManagerFactory&#39; defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.persistence.AttributeConverter
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455) ~[spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.persistence.AttributeConverter
                at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.7.Final.jar:5.0.7.Final]
                at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.7.Final.jar:5.0.7.Final]
                at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:185) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.7.Final.jar:5.0.7.Final]
                at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:34) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.7.Final.jar:5.0.7.Final]
                at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:165) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.7.Final.jar:5.0.7.Final]
                at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:160) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.7.Final.jar:5.0.7.Final]
                at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.7.Final.jar:5.0.7.Final]
                at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:50) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.7.Final.jar:5.0.7.Final]
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:287) ~[spring-orm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) ~[spring-orm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) ~[spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
                ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.AttributeConverter
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:600) ~[na:1.7.0]
                at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:240) ~[bootstrap.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf051507.01]]
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:941) ~[na:1.7.0]
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:876) ~[na:1.7.0]
                at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:133) ~[bootstrap.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf051507.01]]
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:846) ~[na:1.7.0]
                at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf051507.01]]
                at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf051507.01]]
                at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:617) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf051507.01]]
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:846) ~[na:1.7.0]
                at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:617) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:WAS855.SERV1 [cf051507.01]]
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:846) ~[na:1.7.0]
                ... 81 common frames omitted
```

If I use the Hibernate version to support JPA 2.0, then need to use Oracle10gDialect only.

Any idea please from hibernate and webSphere members?

Comment: Why is it relevant to use Oracle12cDialect for you?

Answer (score 1):

No solution for this issue, you can only:

- Upgrade your `Websphere` version to `WAS 9.0` (sure, that's an easy task :) )
- Keep using `Oracle10gDialect` which, aside from version specific details (but I've never encountered any issue in a simple `JPA` use), works just fine with `Oracle 12`.

P.S. There is an [IBM note](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/can-i-use-jpa-2-1-on-websphere-application-server/) about enabling `JPA 2.1` on `WAS 8.5.5` but, honestly, the effort doesn't pay off (no more container managed persistence? No thanks).

Comment: In my case it is not easy to upgrade Websphere to V9. I think Oracle10gDialect can be used as long as there is no specific feature of Oracle 12c Database is required to use. I'm wondering why there is no hibernate version to support Oracle12cDialect and JPA 2.0.

Comment: Because JPA 2.1 is final since 2013... you'll see the same behaviour with JPA 2.2 and later Oracle versions. P.S. I was ironic about upgrading WAS as an easy task.